# Hi, I am trying to create an object in R and then subset the data but am getting an error message regarding dimensions

Tags: r

I am very new at R so I know the fix is simple, I would appreciate if someone could explain to me though my mistake and how to fix it.

```
dat4<-c(10, 11)
subDat<-dat4[,c(10,11)]
```

The error that I am getting is "Error in subDat4<-dat4[,c(10,11)] incorrect number of dimensions"

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow.
You are specifying the dat4 as a vector (one dimension object), but trying to subset as data.frame/tible (2 dimensional objects)...

To specify `dat4[a,b]`, with `a` being the indication for rows, and `b` a indication for columns, you need to have columns and rows (data frame, matrix, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not a matrix, thus,  you can not subset a vector as a matrix. You can only subset matrix with square bracket  as you did.

Try

```
dat4<-c(10, 11)
dat5<-c(12, 13)
mat1<-matrix(c(dat4,dat5),nrow=2)
mat1[1,2]
# 12
```

You can see my subst states row one column two which prints 12, that is the element that falls on row one column two.

If you want to subset the vector you provided you can go this way.

```
 dat4[[1]]
 #[1] 10
```

That show the first element of the vector 'dat4' and

```
 dat4[[2]]
 #[ 11
```

Which show the second element of 'dat4'

I hope this answer is of help to you.